# WCF service for android with json

Tags: c#, android, json, vb.net, wcf

I have a created a WCF service which is used by android. It returns a json string but the actual string data sent by server code is different as accessed.

My Web.Config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="httpBehavior">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>

          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>

          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service name="WcfAndroid.Service1">
        <endpoint address=""
            behaviorConfiguration="httpBehavior"
            binding="webHttpBinding"
            contract="WcfAndroid.IService1" />

      </service>
    </services>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="webHttpBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
     <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

And My WCF Service Interface :

```
<ServiceContract()>
Public Interface IService1

     <OperationContract()> _
        <WebGet(UriTemplate:="GetText", BodyStyle:=WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, responseformat:=WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json)> _
        Function GetText() As String

 End Interface
```

I am returning a constant string from service for testing :

```
Public Function GetText() As String Implements IService1.GetText
    '' GetjsonString()   returns   {"id": 100,"name": "item X","active": true}
    Return GetjsonString()
End Function
```

GetjsonString() function returns String **{"id": 100,"name": "item X","active": true}**

But when service is called it returns :

> {\"id\": 100,\"name\": \"item X\",\"active\": true}

I don't know Why it is not returning the actual string?

Comment: It is valid data you can parse it. It will work as expected.

Comment: when i parse string , it is returning extra slash in string \"id\" . as shown in output

Comment: Try send an object as you are sending string.

Answer (score 0):

I an not really familiar with language so I am not pretty sure how that function works. Do something like this:

```
string.replaceAll("\\", "")
```

to get rid of "\";

What happened with your string is that it have escaped ".

If this is not enough, and clearly this method has flaws, there is an answer to similar problem:
[wcf forces chars escaping in response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3360895/wcf-forces-chars-escaping-in-response)